# AjaxControlToolkit AutoCompleteExtender List Not Showing in Google Chrome

Tags: c#, html, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Using the below code i am successfully able to show auto complete list on text box in Firefox and IE but its not showing in google chrome please help me.
the data from the database is being retrieved successfully. i debugged it and there are no errors.

```
   <style  type="text/css">


.AutoExtender 
{ 
    font-size: 12px; 
    color: #000; 
    padding: 3px 5px; 
    border: 1px solid #999; 
    background: #fff; 
    width: auto; 
    float: left; 
    z-index: 9999999999; 
    position:absolute; 
    margin-left:0px; 
    list-style: none; 
    font-weight: bold; 
} 
        .listItem {
        color: #191919;

        } 
        .itemHighlighted {
        background-color: #ADD6FF;       
        }
</style>


<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" placeholder="SELECT * FROM TABLEA" class="enjoy-css" runat="server"  autocomplete="off"  TextMode="multiline"> 
             </asp:TextBox>

      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>


    <AjaxControlToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender 
    runat="server" 
    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" 
    BehaviorID="AutoCompleteExtender1"
    TargetControlID="TextBox1"
    ServiceMethod="AutoCompleteAjaxRequest"
    ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx"
    MinimumPrefixLength="3" 
    CompletionInterval="100"
    EnableCaching="true"
    CompletionSetCount="100" 
    CompletionListCssClass="AutoExtender"
    CompletionListItemCssClass="listItem"
    FirstRowSelected="true"
    CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="itemHighlighted"
    DelimiterCharacters=";, :\n\r"
    showonlycurrentwordincompletionlistitem="true"
    >
</AjaxControlToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Autocomplete web service

```
    public string[] AutoCompleteAjaxRequest(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        Match match;

        match = Regex.Match(prefixText, "(\\w+)$");


        List<string> ajaxDataCollection = new List<string>();

        if (match.Success)
        {

            String Query = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM(select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  UNION select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ) COLUMN_NAME WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%" +match.Value+"%';";
            DataTable dt = this.GetData(Query, CreateConnectionString(UserName, Password, DatabaseName, DataSource));
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                int countt = dt.Rows.Count;

                for (int i = 0; i < countt; i++)
                {
                    ajaxDataCollection.Add(dt.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
                }
            }

                ajaxDataCollection.Add("SELECT");
                ajaxDataCollection.Add("WHERE");
                ajaxDataCollection.Add("UPDATE");
                ajaxDataCollection.Add("INSERT");
                ajaxDataCollection.Add("DELETE");
                ajaxDataCollection.Add("EXEC");
                ajaxDataCollection.Add("FROM");
                ajaxDataCollection.Add("VALUES");
                ajaxDataCollection.Add("HAVING");

            return  ajaxDataCollection.ToArray();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i removed the AjaxControlToolKit dll file and installed it again using Nuget and it worked... i guess something went wrong when downloading/referencing the previous dll file.

Answer (score 0):

these are the few points i observed in your code :

Add following to the **Autocomplete web service** and make your **web service** method as `static`

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

public static string[] AutoCompleteAjaxRequest(string prefixText, int count)
```

Comment: i am already doing this.. i did not post the whole web service's code and just posted the Service Method that AutoCompleteExtender  use.

Comment: i will try making the method static

Comment: yes for service method add these also `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]`

Comment: no success:/ and also when i changed the method to static, even in Firefox the list stopped showing

Comment: oh i implemented same in my project able to work fine .